# PostgreSQL sum doesn't not calculate sum as intended

Tags: postgresql

```
select distinct userid, SUM(device)  
from table 
where userid != '' 
group by userid, device;

 userid  | sum 
---------+-----
 a       |  12
 b       |   1
 c       |  10
 c       |  78
```

why there is a duplicate userid without no sum calculated. All devices have integer values

Comment: is column "device" of a numerical type?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are grouping by **both** `userid` and `device`. Remove the `device` from the `GROUP BY`.

Your query should look like:

```
select userid, SUM (device)  
from table 
where userid != '' 
group by userid;
```

Incidentally, I removed `DISTINCT` since you are already aggregating.